# Scrapy is not able to find my spiders in the current project

Tags: python, scrapy

I currently have a scrapy project with the following structure:

```
.
├── articlescraper
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── items.pyc
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── pipelines.pyc
│   ├── scheduler.py
│   ├── scheduler.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── nujijspider.py
│       └── nujijspider.pyc
└── scrapy.cfg
```

Now Inside my scheduler.py I call this function:

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading
import time
import sys
import imp
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class Scheduler(object):
    """Scheduler is the base class for the Scheduler
       This class loops on the queue object and calls the needed crawlers from within
       Reschedules articles to be crawled again 
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.articleInformation = {}
        self.taskQueue = Queue()

    def append_work(self, work):
        if work['Url'] not in self.articleInformation:
            self.articleInformation[work['Id']] = work

        print self.articleInformation

    def schedule(self):
        article = self.taskQueue.get()

settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl("articlecommentspider",url="///")
process.start()
```

But this results in this error from scrapy:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 43, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: articlecommentspider'
```

Spider:

```
class ArticleCommentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """ArticleCommentSpider Can look for all the the comments on an article page
       Those article pages are specific to www.nujij.nl and nu.nl related websites 
    """
    name = 'articlecommentspider'
    allowed_domains = ['nujij.nl']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArticleCommentSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    arg = args.get('url')
    if not arg:
        print arg
    self.start_urls = arg


def parse(self,response):
    title = response.xpath("//h1"+matchClass('title')+"//text()").extract()[1] ## Title is weird defined inside Nujij.nl (<h1 class="title">)
    articleId = prog.search(response.url).group().split('.')[0] ## This regex matches things like (873238.lynkx in url)

    response.replace(body=response.body.replace('<br>', '\n')) # Needed for comments which have alot of <br> tags
    for item in response.xpath('//ol[@class="reacties"]//li'+ matchClass('hidenum')): ## Every list item underneath the reactions
        commentId = item.xpath('@id').extract_first() ## Id from the first list item (unique on every article)
        c = item.xpath('.//div[@class="reactie-body "]/text()').extract()
        c = ''.join(map(unicode.strip, c))
        date = item.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="tijdsverschil"])').extract()
        date = dateparser.parse("".join(date))

        articleComment = Comment()
        articleComment['Id'] = articleId+"+"+str(commentId)
        articleComment['Source'] = str(title)
        articleComment['IndexedAt'] = date
        articleComment['Url'] = response.url 
        articleComment['Parser'] = "nujij.nl"
        articleComment['Content'] = str(c)
        articleComment['Subject'] = {
            "url" : response.url, 
            "title": str(title)
        }   
        print articleComment
```

When listing the scrapers with scrapy list I get them both. The scheduler file is also inside the articlescraper project. How can I not call the scraper from within this process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a `scrapy.spider` class not a name of a spider there.

```
from articlescraper.nujijspider import NujijSpider
process.crawl(NujijSpider)
```

Check out [official documentation here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Comment: Also there stands this in the documentation 

`from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

# 'followall' is the name of one of the spiders of the project.
process.crawl('followall', domain='scrapinghub.com')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished`

Comment: hmm, I've never actually tried to use it that way before, but I just tried it on `testspiders` repo the docs recommend and it does in fact work perfectly fine. The structure is pretty much the same on your part. Does `scrapy list` return correct spider names?

Comment: Yes that was why I tought it is so weird. I've changed it to your approach and it works now !